# record doesn't show up if there's no corresponding data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few tables I'm trying to join however, I'm missing some rows if there's no data, but would like to have them be displayed

```
 tblCountry
 sID      sCountry 
 1        Algeria
 2        Armenia
 3        Belgium

 tblRefData
 RefID    IDnum       sID
 1        7           1
 2        8           2
 3        9           3

 tblMData 
 IDnum        IDa
 7            123
 8            123
```

Here's what my query looks like:

```
Select tblCountry.sCountry, count(tblMData.Ida) as CountIDa
From tblRefData 
inner join tblMData on tblRefData.IDnum = tblMData.IDnum
inner join tblCountry on tblRefData.sID = tblCountry.sID
GroupBy tblCountry.sCountry
```

What my desired end result is:

```
sCountry       CountIDa
Algeria        1
Armenia        1
Belgium        0
```

What I'm currently getting is

```
sCountry       CountIDa
Algeria        1
Armenia        1
```

So if country does not have corresponding data in tblMData, that country does not show up in my result. Any ideas?

Comment: HINT:  `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use left join if the on condition columns values  don't match

```
Select 
    tblCountry.sCountry, 
    case 
       when (count(tblMData.Ida) is null) then 0 end as CountIDa
From 
    tblRefData 
left join 
    tblMData on tblRefData.IDnum = tblMData.IDnum
left join 
    tblCountry on tblRefData.sID = tblCountry.sID
Group By 
    tblCountry.sCountry
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the 'INNER JOIN' to a 'LEFT JOIN' to bring back data when there is no corresponding data.  Then you could you the ISNULL() function to set the NULL value to a zero.

Answer (score 1):

You want a `left join`, but have to rearrange the `from` clause:

```
Select c.sCountry, count(m.Ida) as CountIDa
From tblCountry c left join
     tblRefData r
     on r.sID = c.sID left join
     tblMData m
     on r.IDnum = m.IDnum
GroupBy c.sCountry;
```

Notice that the table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.